# HTML/Javascript - Submit a form and show results in shadowbox

Tags: javascript, html, forms, shadowbox

Hi I have a form where the user is required to enter a search term. On the submission of the form, I want the results of the "search.php" page to be displayed in an Iframe inside a shadowbox (Using the shadowbox.js library). I dont know if this is possible or not so any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

```
<form name="search" action="search.php" method="get">
Enter Search Term: <input type="text" name="search">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['search'])){
  $c = $_GET['search'];
  $t = "You searched for" . $c;
}else{
  $t = "Can't find search term!";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Search</title>
</head>
<body style='background-color:#ffffff;'>
<?php echo $t; ?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically, I want the the search.php file to process the form and the result that gets displayed should be shown in a shadowbox, on the same page as the form. Im assuming the search.php page is shown in an iframe and displayed in the shadowbox.

Comment: I believe you can set the `target` of the form to the `name` of the `iframe`. For example `<form name="search" action="search.php" method="get" target="someiframe">` and in the iframe `<iframe ... name="someiframe">`

Comment: Im not necessarily asking how to post to an iframe, im asking how can I make the results of the form be shown in a shadowbox, via an iframe

Comment: I'd be happy to help if you could share more code to help me know exactly what you're looking for. I don't know if a fiddle would work but that'd be great.

Comment: @rosscowar I have added the php code and have added a better explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some AJAX for this. Or well you could pass a iframe by doing...

```
<form name="search" action="javascript:void();" method="get">
Enter Search Term: <input type="text" id="keyword" name="search">
<input type="submit" onClick="search()" value="Submit">
</form> 

<script>
function search() {
    var searchIframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    searchIframe.setAttribute("src","search.php?search="+document.getElementById("keyword").value);
    searchIframe.setAttribute("className","Inset your class with CSS props");
    document.getElementById("shadowBox").appendChild(searchIframe); //Put it in your shadowBox so it will display in the right position you want.
}
</script>
```

That should get it for you. It should implement your iframe for you.

Answer (score 0):

Go get a javascript plugin like [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/), read the documentation, copy-paste like a pro, debug and come back here if you need more help.

> Colorbox - a jQuery lightbox
>
> A lightweight customizable lightbox plugin for jQuery
>
> **Features**
>
> ```
> Supports photos, grouping, slideshow, ajax, inline, and iframed content.
> Lightweight: 10KB of JavaScript (less than 5KBs gzipped).
> Appearance is controlled through CSS so it can be restyled.
> Can be extended with callbacks & event-hooks without altering the source files.
> Completely unobtrusive, options are set in the JS and require no changes to existing HTML.
> Preloads upcoming images in a photo group.
> Well vetted and currently in use in over 600,000 websites.
> ```

Comment: but how can i make the form go straight to the colorbox and the php page display in an iframe in the colorbox?

Comment: Read the documentation, i provided you the link. Helping you is free, doing it for you is 70$USD / hour.